# class property that can be accessed and set by all instances (also of subclasses)

Tags: python

I'd like to set a class property that can be shared by all instances of the class or its subclasses.  It should be possible for any instance to also set the property.

I tried the following:

```
class A:
    x = 1
    @classmethod
    def setX(cls, val):
        if cls.__bases__:
            cls = cls.__bases__[-1]
        cls.x = val
```

This seems to work fine in case of single inheritance.  But if I use multiple inheritance, depending on the order of inheritance, it either works or doesn't  (i.e., class A is not always the last of **bases**).

Any ideas for a robust implementation?

Comment: Setters and getters are a really bad practice in Python - I can't tell if this is just an example for the sake of the question, or something you actually do. If the latter, then check out the [``property()`` builtin/``@property`` decorator](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way, IMO, is to go with a class property. Since properties are tied to an object's classes `__dict__`, as opposed to the object's very own `__dict__`, and since your object happens to be a class, you must attach it to the classes class, its metaclass:

```
class A(object):

    _x = None

    class __metaclass__(type):

        @property
        def x(cls):
            return A._x

        @x.setter
        def x(cls, val):
            A._x = val


class B(A):
    pass

A.x = 'jim'
B.x = 'joe'

print A.x, B.x
```

Result:

```
joe joe
```

Also, your classes must be new style classes, i.e. they must inherit from `object` in Python 2.x. And metaclasses are defined differently in Python 3.x:

```
class MetaA(type):
    """ like ___metaclass__ above """

class A(metaclass=MetaA):

    _x = None

...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use lexical scoping:

```
class A(object):
    x = 1
    @classmethod
    def setX(cls, val):
        A.x = val
```